# Loading modules via RequireJS for large applications

Tags: requirejs

I am working on a fairly large project coming up, and I am (slowly) finding the ins and outs with requireJS. I can say I love it (the concept) and doubt I'll ever go back to "the old way." That said, I'd like to develop good habitats from the start.

I have a main module called `application.js`

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Primary application module.
 * 
 * @param {function} jquery | jQuery library. http://jquery.com/
 * @returns {object}
 * 
 */
define([
    'jquery'
], function (jquery) {
    var Application = {
        /**
         * Initialization method.
         * 
         * @returns {void}
         * 
         */
        initalize: function () {
            // Start doing stuff...

        }
    };

    return Application;
});
```

So far so good.
What I' curious about, is when I start adding more and more modules. Let's say at some point I have a "contact us" form or some other module that doesn't necessarily need loaded at start up, but will need to be available on page "x".

Would I load it in the list of initial dependencies like this:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Primary application module.
 * 
 * @param {function} jquery | jQuery library. http://jquery.com/
 * @param {object} moduleone | ModuleOne
 * @returns {object}
 * 
 */
define([
    'jquery'
    'moduleone'
], function (jquery, ModuleOne) {
    var Application = {
        /**
         * Initialization method.
         * 
         * @returns {void}
         * 
         */
        initalize: function () {
            // Start doing stuff...

            if ($('#moduleOneThing').length) {
                 // Do stuff with ModuleOne...
            }
        }
    };

    return Application;
});
```

Or is it better to set another define/require block like this:

'use strict';

```
/**
 * Primary application module.
 * 
 * @param {function} jquery | jQuery library. http://jquery.com/
 * @param {object} moduleone | ModuleOne
 * @returns {object}
 * 
 */
define([
    'jquery'
], function (jquery) {
    var Application = {
        /**
         * Initialization method.
         * 
         * @returns {void}
         * 
         */
        initalize: function () {
            // Start doing stuff...

            if ($('#moduleOneThing').length) {
                 require(['moduleone'], function (ModuleOne) {
                     // Do stuff with Module One...
                 });
            }
        }
    };

    return Application;
});
```

Or, perhaps I'm way off on everything. In any case I would like to learn the "correct" way from the start in hopes to not have to break bad habits down the road. This is an extremely simple example, but the complexity will grow quickly and I am hopeful to set things up correctly to avoid a pile of steaming garbage in the next few weeks.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'd use the second option, but make sure to add some loading screen, so that the user does not just see a white page, while waiting on the module.

Comment: You may want to take a look at my project [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy). It leverages r.js to split the application into separate bundles (e.g. per view), instead of a single monolithic script. Also, I recently came across [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/), haven't had time to evaluate it though.